# Should I register the domain name that has not popular top level domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

Let's say for example you want to register domain name `assembly.com` or `assembly.net` and find out that they are already registered (not available).

Would you go with the domain name `assemb.ly` in such case?
By having `.ly` the domain name represent word `assembly` but I think `.ly` domain is not so friendly for search engines?

What do you think?

Do you see any advantage of `asemb.ly` over `assembly.com` or `assembly.net` except it is shorter?

Comment: It makes it a bit more difficult to explain, but I always have a small spark of "ha, I like the creativity". You could easily make the `.ly` the main domain, and header-301 the .com version to it. Both work, both benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on the requirements. The `.ly` domain name represent their business in Libya. If my targeted visitors OR business is relevant to Libya I will surely consider it. Else, look for an other alternative OR domain name.

Comment: The business does not have anything in common with Ligya. The `.ly` represents the last two letters of the word `assembly`

Comment: @sreginogemoh You should perform some research if this domain is a global TLD  or a regional domain that would automatically get geotargetted to its country. If latter is the case, I would not buy it as a lot of Search Engines will assume that your audience are in that specific country (libya in this case).

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll find you probably need both - while `assemb.ly` might be slightly shorter, explaining to people that it's "assemb dot el why" will probably take longer than `assembly.com`.

Many of the brands that make use of this particular TLD do so as a URL shortening process, but they then tend to resolve on a more common TLD, for example the Bitly domain `bit.ly` redirects to bitly.com, similarly `ow.ly` for hootsuite.com and so on.

Note also that you may well fall under far more stringent content regulation if that is your primary domain - [this article](http://benmetcalfe.com/blog/2010/10/the-ly-domain-space-to-be-considered-unsafe/) from 2010 talks about the case of a domain being seized by NIC.ly because

> the content of our website, in their opinion, fell outside of Libyan Islamic/Sharia Law

As has been noted, the .ly TLD is considered a "country code TLD" (it's not on Google's list of [Geotargetable domains](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922)), and so will probably rank higher when searching from within Libya than for people outside of it. Your best hope is that you don't use a CDN, [and host the servers in your local country so that Google can use the IP address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2) to help localise you.

Comment: It is not "considered" a country code, it **is** a country code, delegated as such by IANA to the corresponding local government, see https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ly.html which also means that any domain under `.ly` needs to abide by the registry rules, derived from the country laws. So care should be taken to analyze those laws and rules before registering the domain names. This is of course the same for any other TLD, and ones have to remind that .COM/.NET does depend on US laws.